# explode list of emails separated with different characters in php

Tags: php, regex, explode

I have a form where i can get a list of emails separated by random characters:
(some will use comma, others will use semi-colon or even *). Something like this:

```
email1@example.com;email2@example.com,email3@example.com*email4@example.com
```

Is there a way to explode the string with a regular expression?

In most cases, the users will type the same separator but i don't want to force people with an exclusive one.

Comment: Short answer is yes, this can be accomplished with regular expressions. Long answer is, let's see your attempt.

Comment: Alternatively, you could insist on people using just one seperator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should get you started:

```
<?php
$test = preg_split ('/(;|,|\*)/', 'email1@example.com;email2@example.com,email3@example.com*email4@example.com');

var_dump($test);
```

[Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) and [demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/edSF8d)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [preg_split](http://uk.php.net/preg_split) function.

Here is a quick example & output:

```
<?php
    $str = "email1@example.com;email2@example.com,email3@example.com*email4@example.com";
    $finalString=preg_split("/[*,;]/",$str);
    var_dump($finalString);
?>
```

OUTPUT:

```
array
  0 => string 'email1@example.com' (length=18)
  1 => string 'email2@example.com' (length=18)
  2 => string 'email3@example.com' (length=18)
  3 => string 'email4@example.com' (length=18)
```

Answer (score 1):

For a complete solution you can use [preg_match_all()](http://uk.php.net/preg_match_all)

```
$emails = preg_match_all(
    "/[a-z0-9]+([_\\.-][a-z0-9]+)*@([a-z0-9]+([\.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+\\.[a-z]{2,}/i",
    $emails,
    $matches
);
```

`$matches[0]` array will have all your emails.

Answer (score 0):

See it **[in action](http://regexr.com?31vb8)**:

```
(?<mail>[\w%+.-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6})
```

Comment: Careful, this fails if the local part of the e-mail address contains a period (e.g., first.m.last@department.example.name). Looking for the separator is generally a mucher safer approach.

Comment: @user113215 Easy to fix. Added dot for the first part also, now matches your example.